# FontAwesome 5 setup in Angular 6 with Angular Materials using the <mat-icon> directive

Tags: angular6, font-awesome-5, angular-material-6

Baseline:

- Angular 6.0.3
- Angular Materials 6.4.2
- "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.1.1"
- "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2"
- "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.2.0"

  So I have installed angular-fontawesome and I'm trying to get the `<mat-icon>` directive to work, but its not.  I was unclear on how to register the fonts or if I even needed too.  I'm looking for an example of where someone is using the new font-awesome with angular and what is needed to use the `<mat-icon>` directive to get the icons to display.  If I follow the instructions on the angular-font-awesome GitHub page it all works, but they are using tags like this:  `<fa-icon icon="coffee"></fa-icon>`

Can someone please go through the setup so I can get these to render using the `<mat-icon>` directive.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748824/2167021.

Answer (score 3):

Taken straight from [this link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11630), implemented and working into my project, these are the steps I followed.

1. Install relevant FontAwesome libraries

   ```
   npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
   npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
   npm i @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
   npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
   ```
2. Create icon service

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
   import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class IconService {
     constructor(private _iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
     addSvg(icon: IconDefinition) {
       const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ${icon.icon[0]} ${icon.icon[1]}">
           <path d="${icon.icon[4]}" />
         </svg>`;

       this._iconRegistry.getNamedSvgIcon(icon.iconName, icon.prefix).subscribe(
         () => {
           //Ok, icon already exists
         },
         () => {
           //Error, not found, add it
           this._iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteralInNamespace(
             icon.prefix,
             icon.iconName,
             this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(svg)
           );
         }
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add the icons you require, this should be done on an as-needs basis to prevent bundle bloat

   ```
   // In app.component or relevant component requiring icon
   import { faGoogle } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
   /*...*/
   constructor(
     _iconService: IconService
   ) {
     _iconService.addSvg(faGoogle); // add icon to library
   }
   ```
4. Use your icon

   ```
   <mat-icon svgIcon="fab:google"></mat-icon>
   ```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer! Thank you!

Comment: But usage in `mat-icon-button` is troubling. If you set smaller button your icon clips, if you set smaller icon via css button remains the same.