# Angular Using Mat-Icons with PrimeIcons

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, primeng

I have an angular app that is using material icons. I created a component that uses primeng's org chart but the icons on the org chart are not using primeicons instead are using materials icons. It looks like the  tag is being modified which is messing up the styling of the org chart. I would like this component to not inherit the material  styling. I tried setting ViewEncapsulation to None and then removing the ViewEncapsulation settings but nothing changes. I also tried adding this to the css file:

```
i {
   font-family: 'primeicons'
{
```

or this:

```
i {
   all: unset
}
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It's not that straightforward to use different font-family icons with Angular material. You should take a look at this StackOverflow thread; it is a similar scenario but with fontawesome icons
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025162/use-font-awesome-5-on-angular-material-7